# JUnit with nested Java and Xml Spring Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I'm trying to introduce JUnit in my Spring MVC application and I'm using mix of java and xml configuration (my java config use xml to autowire some variable) to define my beans:

// 1 - My test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MvcConfiguration_Test.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ClassTest {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("databaseTest")
  DataBaseConn conn;

  @Test
  public void test() {
    // do some stuff
  }
}
```

// 2 - Java Configuration

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "applicationContext.xml" }) // this file is in classpath, actually I'm using "classpath:**/applicationContext.xml" but the next step is to move this file in resources/test :)
public class MvcConfiguration_Test extends MvcConf{

  @Autowired
  String dbName; // defined in applicationContext.xml

  @Bean
  public DataBaseConn databaseTest(){
    DataBaseConn conn = new DataBaseConn();
    conn.addDataSource(dbName, jndi, user, pwd)
    return conn;
  }
}
```

// 3 - xml configuration - applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...
  <context:annotation-config />
  <bean id="dbName" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="myDb"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

When I launch my JUnit test, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConfiguration_Test': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: java.lang.String package.MvcConfiguration_Test.dbName; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

The workaround is to wire the name of db in dirty way:
String dbName = "myDb";
but this is not the desired solution :)

PS. My MVC application is autowiring the value correclty (I only remove `@ComponentScan("ct.cbi")` from MvcConfiguration to read the test configuration.

Comment: Autowiring a String bean seems odd to me. I feel like reading this value from a properties file would be a better way to do this. It's certainly not something I've seen before.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot autowire String as mentioned in Spring [documention](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-exceptions):

> You cannot autowire so-called simple properties such as primitives, Strings, and Classes (and arrays of such simple properties). This limitation is by-design.

What I would suggest is to define a property in your application.properties file so you'll be able to externalize this kind of information.

You should have a look at [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for further information.

Comment: You're right but my problem is not related to this. To make sure of that, I changed the type: 
`@Autowired
DbNameBean dbNameBean;`
and in applicationContext.xml>
`<bean id="dbNameBean" class="package.DbNameBean">
  <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="myDb"/>
</bean>`
but still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be that your applicationContext.xml is not visible on the test classpath. You would need to move it to test/resources to make it work.

But as @Rlarroque mentioned in his answer you really should consider a properties solution for configuring your DB name. For a start it would let you reconfigure the DB name without having to rebuild the whole application.

Comment: You are both right :) but before I configure my enviroment in the right way, I need to make it work :) As I said in my question, applicationContext.xml is in classpath. I tried to remove the file from classpath and the exception is: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/applicationContext.xml]`. Thank you however for your engagement.